# @State variable is not updated the first time I set it

Tags: swiftui

In this simple example, the user selects a word from a list, and then I show their selection in a modal sheet. I store their selection in a `@State` variable, and update another `@State` to control the presentation of my modal sheet. However, this doesn't work on the first selection - the first time, I see the fallback "nothing selected". It works as expected on subsequent selections. What am I not understanding about `@State`?

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    @State var selectedOption: String? = nil
    @State var isShowingModal = false
    let options = ["Cat", "Dog", "Horse"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                Button(option) {
                    selectedOption = option
                    isShowingModal = true
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingModal) {
            if let option = selectedOption {
                Text(option)
            } else {
                Text("Nothing selected")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@State` var is working fine.

The problem is that `sheet` can pre-render its contents. Since you want to present and pass in a value at the same time, try the [`sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)) modifier:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedOption: String? = nil /// Just this one property is good enough.
    let options = ["Cat", "Dog", "Horse"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                Button(option) {
                    selectedOption = option /// After setting the property, the sheet will automatically present.
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $selectedOption) { option in /// `option` will be the selected String.
            Text(option)
        }
    }
}

/// Make `String` conform to `Identifiable`.
extension String: Identifiable {
    public var id: String {
        return self
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to extend `Identifiable` conformance to all strings (in case you have a huge codebase or something), a wrapper struct will work:

```
struct Option: Identifiable {
    var id: String { string } /// Satisfies the `Identifiable` protocol.
    var string: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedOption: Option? = nil

    let options = [
        Option(string: "Cat"),
        Option(string: "Dog"),
        Option(string: "Horse")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            ForEach(options) { option in /// Note! Since `Option` conforms to `Identifiable`, you don't need the `id: \.self` here.
.
                Button(option.string) {
                    selectedOption = option
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $selectedOption) { option in
            Text(option.string)
        }
    }
}
```